# How to use regex with String.split()

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following String:

```
String fullPDFContex = "Title1 Title2\r\nTitle3 Title4\r\n\r\nTitle5 Title6\r\n \r\n Title7 \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
```

I want to convert it to an array of String which will look like this.

```
String[] Title = {"Title1 Title2","Title3 Title4","Title5 Title6","Title7"}
```

I am trying the following code.

```
String[] Title=fullPDFContext.split("\r\n\r\n|\r\n \r\n|\r\n");
```

But not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split with a pattern that matches any amount of whitespace that contains a line break:

```
String fullPDFContex = "Title1 Title2\r\nTitle3 Title4\r\n\r\nTitle5 Title6\r\n \r\n Title7 \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
String separator = "\\p{javaWhitespace}*\\R\\p{javaWhitespace}*";
String results[] = fullPDFContex.split(separator);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
// => [Title1 Title2, Title3 Title4, Title5 Title6, Title7]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/l5Kzg2).

The `\\p{javaWhitespace}*\\R\\p{javaWhitespace}*` matches

- `\\p{javaWhitespace}*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\R` - a line break (you may replace it with `[\r\n]` for Java 7 and older)
- `\\p{javaWhitespace}*` - 0+ whitespaces.

Alternatively, you may use a bit more efficient

```
String separator = "[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*\\R\\s*";
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/UOR1Gt)

Unfortunately, the `\R` construct cannot be used in the character classes. The pattern will match:

- `[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*` - zero or more whitespace chars other than CR and LF (character class subtraction is used here)
- `\\R`  - a line break
- `\\s*` - any 0+ whitespace chars.

Comment: Well, `\\p{javaWhitespace}` might be too long. A similar, but more efficient pattern is `"[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*\\R\\s*"` or `"[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*[\r\n]\\s*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. we can use **StringTokenizer** & I have used list to insert the splitted values.This can help you if you have n number of values splitted from your array

```
package com.sujit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class UserInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fullPDFContex = "Title1 Title2\r\nTitle3 Title4\r\n\r\nTitle5 Title6\r\n \r\n Title7 \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(fullPDFContex, "\r\n");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {

            list.add(token.nextToken());
        }
        for (String string : list) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you get the output you want:

```
String[] Title = fullPDFContext.split(" *(\r\n ?)+ *");
```

Comment: This will not work if the line break is `\n` or `\r`, and if there are tabs before/after a line break. See my solution that handles that all.

Comment: Your answer is more complete (and was accepted). My answer made  (intentionally) no assumptions on what the OP wanted.